# What is the proper SQLAlchemy Type to store big strings?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning sqlalchemy and I am a little confused about what type should I use to store data, which can be even 20000 character long. Is it a good idea to use `Unicode(20000)`? I am afraid, that in case of shorter texts I will waste to much memory.

Comment: Based on http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html, `String` seems to be the more suitable.

Comment: @fedorqui: there is "Certain databases may require a length", so I am not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that type of data you can use [Text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text) or [UnicodeText](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.UnicodeText). They do not require you to specify length.